# Как отлаживать программу без IDE с++?

Tags: c++, память, отладка, ide

допустим у меня есть програмка:

```
int main() {
    int* array = new int[10];
}
```

Как обнаружить утечку памяти без использования каких-либо IDE? Ну и вообщем как производить отладку без IDE?
Программа будет собрана с помощью mingw + cmake

Comment: так Вам отладку или утечку? очень похоже на вопрос для собеседования.

Comment: ох. ну какая "вижла"...

Comment: если Вам прям так поставили задание - бегите. срочно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Начнем с простого. Отладка. Тут все просто. при компиляции добавляете -g или -ggdb (если как отладчик будет использоваться gdb). И теперь можно использовать любой отладчик ([gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170097/adding-gdb-to-mingw), [x64db](https://x64dbg.com/#start) или Windbg, который идет "как бы со студией" (на самом деле с sdk), а может даже OllyDbg - тут все индивидуально. Мне лично нравится gdb). Дальше читаете инструкцию на отладчик и все будет.

Например, если это gdb, то запуск будет такой  `gdb ./имябинарника`. поставить точку останова - `b имя функции` `b номер строки`. run - запустить. с - продолжать выполнение. s/n - пошаговый проход. `p имяпеременной` - печать переменной. Этого обычно с головой хватает.

Теперь поиск утечек. Раньше с этим было чуть сложнее, но теперь все упростилось. Если gcc достаточно свежий (вроде от 4.8 и старше), то есть встроенные санитайзеры. Просто добавляете при компиляции `-fsanitize=address`, компилируете и запускаете. И теперь компилятор добавит немного кода (да, программа будет чуточку медленнее работать) и по ходу выполнения и в конце покажет в консоли много полезной информации - о забытом free, о использовании после освобождения, о двойном освобождении. Если отладочная информация включена, то там будут номера строк, куда стоит посмотреть. [здесь](https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_use_address_sanitizer) можно посмотреть как это выглядит.

Ах да, ещё упоминался cmake. А он не нужен в данном случае. Ну разве что для передачи параметров компиляции. Если у Вас реально один cpp, то можно компилировать прям так в консоли.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Тоже предложил gdb, на что мне ответили "не знаю" 

Comment: ещё один признак того, что скорее всего с той стороны "не знают ничего"

Comment: в правке пытались предложить -g3/-ggdb3 вместо просто -g/-ggdb. Вряд ли это нужно. по умолчанию там и так используется второй уровень, а третий добавляет ну совсем тонкие моменты. Нужно ли это - я не знаю

Comment: @KoVadim - офигенный по концентрации полезнйоинформации ответ! Часть язнал, но тут всё в одном месте и сразу!

Comment: а теперь контрольный - в gdb, если только никто не помешал, есть встроенный ui:) в консоли gdb пишите tui enable (ну и tui disable для выключения). tui reg reg/tui reg all, что бы увидеть регистры. И Ваша жизнь не будет больше прежней.

Comment: вот ждал минусатора. и он подтянулся. Молодец анонимный минусатор

Comment: @KoVadim а если проект большой и используется cmake для сборки, куда добавлять -fsanitize=address

Comment: посмотрите на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320465/whats-the-proper-way-to-enable-addresssanitizer-in-cmake-that-works-in-xcode - там вроде все приведено.

Comment: @KoVadim да видел этот вопрос, делал так же, вылетает ошибка. `D:/Mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lasan
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: там в одном с ответов написано, что для линкера тоже нужно добавить опций

Comment: @KoVadim `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -fsanitize=address")
set(CMAKE_LDFLAGS "${CMAKE_LDFLAGS} -fsanitize=address")
add_executable(test main.cpp)`
я  вроде всё добавил но ошибка остается)

Comment: взял этот cmake, отформатировал как нужно и все завелось и скомпилилось. Может mingw так не умеет?

Comment: похоже оно не умеет https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/3163

Comment: @KoVadim а как тогда искать лики? Там сборка под мингв...

Comment: Clang под windows вроде как поддерживают https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html но нужно экспериментировать.